# Soapstone Stamp Translation

Tags: translation, character-identification

I was wondering if someone could help me identify the two characters on the bottom of this soapstone seal? I've tried to work it out, but these characters are quite unfamiliar to me / stylised in a way I've not seen before.

I've flipped the image horizontally, so it should look as it would on paper (assuming the image was correctly flipped to begin with!)

[image: soapstone seal]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

read it as “占美”, most likely a transliteration of “jimmy”